# What are the Fock-state probabilities of general Gaussian states?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-optics, phase-space, coherent-states, wigner-transform

A general (pure) Gaussian state has the form $\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1\rangle}\ket{\alpha,\xi}\equiv D(\alpha)S(\xi)\ket{\on{vac}}$, with $\ket{\on{vac}}$ the vacuum state, $D(\alpha)\equiv\exp(\alpha a^\dagger-\alpha^* a)$ the displacement operator, and $S(\xi)\equiv\exp(\frac12 \xi a^{\dagger 2}-\frac12\xi^* a^2)$ the squeezing operator.

I'm interested in the Fock state probabilities of such a state as a function of $\alpha,\xi\in\mathbb C$, that is, the values
$$P_k\equiv \langle k|\alpha,\xi \rangle \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{k!}}\langle \on{vac}| a^k|\alpha,\xi\rangle, \qquad k\in\mathbb N$$
What are good ways to compute these?

Two "natural" approaches are (1) the direct calculation decomposing the operators as a sum of creations and annihilation operators, and (2) passing through the Wigner representation of Gaussian states. Other "better" routes are likely also viable.

Following the former path, I get, applying BCH and other standard techniques to rearrange the exponential expressions, to the expression:
$$
  \langle n|\alpha,\xi\rangle =
  \frac{e^{|\alpha|^2/2}}{\sqrt{n!\cosh(|\xi|)}}
\alpha^n \sum_{\ell,k\ge0} (-|\alpha|^2)^\ell (C/\alpha^2)^k \frac{(n+\ell)!}{\ell! k! (\ell+n-2k)!} $$
with $C\equiv \frac12 e^{i\theta_\xi} \tanh(|\xi|)$ and $\xi=|\xi|e^{i\theta_\xi}$.
I cannot get this into a useful closed formula. Assuming this is possible at all, knowing the solution obtained from another route (*e.g.* via the Wigner representation or similar) might shed light into how to handle this.

Comment: Schleich does not do it in his book?

Comment: Suggestion for a possible "better route":  if you can swap $D(\alpha)$ with $a^k$ by knowing $[D(\alpha), a^k]$, then you can express your state as: $(D(\alpha)|0)^*a^k*S(E)|0\rangle$. Since $D(\alpha)|0\rangle$ and $S(E)|0\rangle$ both have explicit fock state expansions, you just need to simplify the product at the end.

Comment: Actually...looking at your final expression it looks pretty similar to what would come out of my suggested "better route" - so I guess it ends up being the same in the end?

Comment: Maybe try the math stackexchange to see if there are any binomial coefficient identities that can get that double sum to converge?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I can't find any mention of Gaussian states in the version I could find. Can you point to where this is discussed?

Comment: @StevenSagona the way I did it was writing $D(\alpha)=e^{-\alpha^* a}e^{\alpha a^\dagger} e^{|\alpha|^2/2}$ and $S(\xi)=e^{C a^{\dagger 2}}e^{-\ln\cosh(|\xi|)(N+1/2)}e^{-C^* a^2}$. Then the expval automatically contains operators in antinormal order and you get something like $\frac{e^{|\alpha|^2/2}}{\sqrt{n!\cosh(|\xi|)}}\langle a^n e^{-\alpha^* a}e^{\alpha a^\dagger}e^{C a^{\dagger 2}}\rangle$. Expanding the exponentials and doing some index juggling I get to the expression in the post. I'd guess methods that just take care of the ordering of the ops should lead to the same expression

Comment: It was a question, not a hint. There is so much stuff in there, including in the problems...

Comment: Gerry and Knight, Chapter 7. https://i.imgur.com/fpdOC1l.png

Comment: @Kamil thanks, I'll have a look at the derivation there